# SonarLint for Visual Studio 2015 does not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarlint

I have VS2015 Enterprise with Update 3. It installs fine but when I select "Manage SonarQube connections" from the Analyze menu, an error box appears saying 'The SonarLintIntegrationPackage' package did not load correctly.

I have restarted Visual Studio, restarted Windows (I'm on 8.1) and tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension.

The error message suggests looking at the ActivityLog.xml, and below I list the error details

```
<entry>
    <record>520</record>
    <time>2017/02/07 11:08:29.896</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [SonarLintIntegrationPackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces&apos; Description: Value cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: option&#x000D;&#x000A;System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: option&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Options.OptionKey..ctor(IOption option, String language)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Integration.Vsix.SolutionAnalysisRequester.FindFullSolutionAnalysisOptionKey(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IWorkspaceConfigurator workspaceConfigurator)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Integration.Vsix.SolutionAnalysisRequester..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IWorkspaceConfigurator workspaceConfigurator)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Integration.Vsix.SonarAnalyzerManager..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Workspace workspace)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at SonarLint.VisualStudio.Integration.Vsix.SonarLintIntegrationPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
    <guid>{68D6A325-11E8-4790-A4BA-0EDD001FB080}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>521</record>
    <time>2017/02/07 11:08:29.909</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [SonarLintIntegrationPackage](null)</description>
    <guid>{68D6A325-11E8-4790-A4BA-0EDD001FB080}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>522</record>
    <time>2017/02/07 11:08:29.911</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [SonarLintIntegrationPackage]</description>
    <guid>{68D6A325-11E8-4790-A4BA-0EDD001FB080}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Any ideas on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 1

I have also tried deleting the contents of
C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentMod‌​elCache

But it has not fixed the issue

UPDATE 2

I also deleted the contents of C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

Then opened VS as admin but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I deleted the contents of C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and it worked.

It may not be the optimal solution as I have lost customizations and some extensions (although I backed it all up so I could get it all back).